# prevent axios from sending refresh token request when it has already been requested

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an axios interceptor that sends a request for refreshing the access token when the original request gets 401 error but the problem is even though it requested a refresh token when another request is sent and gets 401 it sends the refresh token request again!.
It keeps sending requests for refreshing the access token when there is already a refresh token request pending.
How can I prevent that?

```
const createResponseInterceptor = () => {
const interceptor = axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    (error: AxiosError) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response && error.response.status !== 401) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        axiosClient.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

        console.info('token expired', error.response?.config);

        return axiosClient
            .patch('/auth', {
                refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    localStorage.setItem(
                        'access_token',
                        res.data.accessToken
                    );

                    axiosClient.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                        res.data.accessToken;
                    originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                        res.data.accessToken;

                    return axiosClient(originalRequest);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');

                    window.location.href = '/login';

                    return Promise.reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.info('error failed');
                    axiosClient.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

                    return Promise.reject(err);
                }
            })
            .finally(createResponseInterceptor);
    }
);
```

};

This is my interceptor code it works just fine but I only have this one problem.